# Opensea - To first time sell I need to sign messeage & Sign a message using your wallet to continue but it shows error afterwards [Picture shown]

Tags: solidity, erc-20, nft, polygon, opensea

This is my first time selling and it says that I need to "sign message" shown here. I did that but I got the error is shown below instead of approval: Any advice on how I can fix this issue will reward the one who succeed support us.  [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend, clear your browser cache, wait 5 minutes and then sign the message again. Mostly working.